# How do I avoid getting "initializer element is not constant" when calling gtk_accelerator_name in a static array?

Tags: c, gtk, constants

I changed this:

```
static GtkActionEntry menu_items[] = {
  { "OpenFile", GTK_STOCK_OPEN, NULL, "<control>O", NULL, G_CALLBACK(file_open) },
  ...
},
```

... to this:

```
static GtkActionEntry menu_items[] = {
  { "OpenFile", GTK_STOCK_OPEN, NULL, gtk_accelerator_name(GDK_o, GDK_CONTROL_MASK), NULL, G_CALLBACK(file_open) }, 
  ...
},
```

... and now I get "error: initializer element is not constant".  What changes do I need to make to get this working?

[GtkActionEntry](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkActionGroup.html#GtkActionEntry)'s fourth argument is a gchar pointer and [gtk_accelerator_name](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-Keyboard-Accelerators.html#gtk-accelerator-name) returns that as far as I can see.

menu_items is used in a static function, like this:

```
static gint nmenu_items = sizeof (menu_items) / sizeof (menu_items[0]);

static GtkWidget *get_menubar_menu(GtkWidget *win) {
  GtkActionGroup *action_group = gtk_action_group_new("Menu");
  gtk_action_group_add_actions(action_group, menu_items, nmenu_items, 0);
  ...
}
```

Comment: The reason for the error has been provided by unwind. Its not that the fourth argument of `GtkActionEntry` is `gchar*` & `gtk_accelerator_name` returns `gchar*` but you declare `menu_items[]` as `static`. The problem is at compile-time you wont know what `gtk_accelerator_name` will return. You wont have the error if you make `menu_items[]` non-`static`.

Comment: I get the same error when removing "static".  But I guess I should create that array in a function instead.

Comment: You are right... Please ignore the comment! Sorry for the misdirection!

Comment: As you have rightly found the solution, the way to solve this is to have it in function as the globals have to be initialized with constant expression just like statics. Alternatively make `menu_items` a pointer or have the number of elements fixed & you have can a function which will initialize `menu_items`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that, the `static` data needs to be determined at compile-time, but `gtk_accelerator_name()` probably resides in a shared object that might not even be available when you compile.

So, you need to add code to go through the array once at startup, before you actually use it in the call to `gtk_action_group_add_actions()`, to pass each string to `gtk_accelerator_name()` as needed.